WINDOWS: Open external programs with python, keep them opened after terminating the script
I've written a python script that (via a UI) lets me open files in different programs (for instance Microsoft Word).
The problem is that, when I terminate the Python script, the programs also close.
How do I prevent this?
This is how the script opens files at the moment:
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
subprocess.Popen(['start', '', file_path], shell=True, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS)

Adding this: CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, also doesn't work.
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing


What is the purpose of requiring shell=True and running start? It probably makes sense to run file_path as a subprocess directly instead.

Indeed, why use start at all? If you want to execute an application, just pass the application path. The current code tries to detach Windows Explorer's start command not Word
